# How I can store payload in a variable after UI action in robot framework

Tags: robotframework, web-api-testing

```
Input Text          id:login_username   ${Username}
Input Password      id:login_password    ${Password}
Click Element       //span[contains(text(),'login')]
```

I want to store payload data after click Login. Can someone have solution please help me

Comment: Which payload? Do you mean the request that the pressing login button event has been sent? Please add more information.

Comment: yesss! What events occur after pressing login button?

example
${Username} = admin
${Password} =  P@ss

What data in api login has been sent ?

Data in payload is appear : 
username: admin
password: P@ss

I want to store values of username 'admin' and password 'P@ss' in valiables for apply next.